# EXCEL - List in one cell of positions of cells in a range that match 1 criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with some values and blank cells.
I would like to get the relative position in that range of all not blank cells, and those positions listed in a single cell as string.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| xx | Positions of cells with value |
| xx | 1,2,4,8 |
|  |  |
| xx |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| xx |  |

I think a combination of INDEX, MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A2:A9)) and CONCATENATE would do it but so far I haven't been able to make it work.

I could get it with:
`=CONCATENATE(,IF(ISBLANK(A2),,"1,"),IF(ISBLANK(A3),,"2,",.....)`
but it's very cumbersome :(

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

(PS: I don't have the last version with the new functions)

Comment: Can you use VBA to achieve this, or does it have to be a formula?

Comment: Hmm I can only think of adding an extra column B, in cell B2 the formula can be `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",ROW(A2)&", ")`. Then drag the formula down column B. Then the formula for cell C2 can be `=CONCAT(B:B)`. I can't really think of how to do it in one cell

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alph!
But I think you're right, VBA is the way to do it.
Here's the function I wrote:

```
Public Function RegPos(ByRef rng As Range)
    
'Initialization
Dim I&, K&, N&, nR&, OK() As Boolean
nR = rng.Rows.Count
N = 0: K = 0
ReDim OK(nR)
 
'Counter of cells with values
For I = 1 To nR
    If Not IsEmpty(rng(I, 1)) Then
    OK(I) = True
    Else: OK(I) = False
End If
  If OK(I) Then N = N + 1
Next I

If N = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim Pos(1 To N) As String

'Fill with position of valid cells
For I = 1 To nR
  If OK(I) Then
    K = K + 1
    Pos(K) = I
  End If
Next I

RegPos = Join(Pos, ",")

End Function`
```